# Interpreting the output of double integral over a Circle

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, regions

```
Clear["Global`*"];

f[x_, y_] := 9 - x^2 - y^2;

Integrate[f[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -Sqrt[1 - x^2], Sqrt[1 - x^2]}]

Integrate[f[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Disk[]]
```

Both give:

> (17 π)/2

---

Visualization:

```
p1 = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}
   , PlotStyle -> None
   , PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}, {0, 10}}
   , ClippingStyle -> None
   , ImageSize -> 400
   ];
p2 = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Disk[]
   , Filling -> Bottom
   , FillingStyle -> Opacity[0.5]
   , PlotRange -> {0, 9}
   ];
Show[p1, p2]
```

[image]

---

**Question**

What (if any) is a possible interpretation for `16 π` that is generated by:

```
Integrate[f[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Circle[]]
```

---

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It is the area of lateral curved surface of the cylinder. Radius of the cylinder is `1` so its circumference is `2π`, its height is `8`, i.e. the area is `2π*8 = 16 π`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Integrate[f[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Circle[]]
```

> `16 π`

is the  line integrate https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral

$$\int_{\mathcal{C}} f(\mathbf{r})\, ds = \int_a^b f\left(\mathbf{r}(t)\right) \left|\mathbf{r}'(t)\right| \, dt$$
the same as

```
(* $Version 14.0 *)
f[x_, y_] := 9 - x^2 - y^2;
LineIntegrate[f[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Circle[{0, 0}, 1]]
```

> `16 π`.

We can also calculus it by the definiton of line integral.

```
f[x_, y_] := 9 - x^2 - y^2;
x[t_] := Cos[t];
y[t_] := Sin[t];
Integrate[
 f[x[t], y[t]]  Sqrt[{x'[t], y'[t]} . {x'[t], y'[t]}], {t, 0, 
  2  π}]
Integrate[f[x[t], y[t]]  Norm[{x'[t], y'[t]}], {t, 0, 2  π}]
```

> `16 π`

Comment: So the surface area of the vertical side of the light yellow cylinder in the image above?

Comment: @Syed  I don't know the general case, but for this special case, we can use  `reg = ImplicitRegion[{0 <= z <= 9 - x^2 - y^2, {x, y} ∈ 
      Circle[]}, {x, y, z}] // Region;
{reg, reg // Area}`

Answer (score 1):

```
IntegrateChangeVariables[
 Inactive[Integrate][f[x, y], 
{x, -1, 1}, {y, -Sqrt[1 - x^2], Sqrt[1 - x^2]}], 
{r, \[Theta]},
 "Cartesian" -> "Polar"]
```

(*
Inactive[Integrate][-r (-9 + r^2), {r, 0,
1}, {[Theta], -[Pi], [Pi]}]
*)

```
Activate[%]
```

(17 [Pi])/2

Comment: Please accept my apologies. I have split the question. It was clumsy of me. Could you please move this answer over to the new question where it would be a perfect match. Thanks.

Comment: What new question?

Comment: [297845](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/297845/setting-up-a-double-integral-over-a-polar-region)