# Setting up a double integral over a polar region

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, regions

```
Clear["Global`*"];

f[x_, y_] := 9 - x^2 - y^2;

Integrate[f[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -Sqrt[1 - x^2], Sqrt[1 - x^2]}]

Integrate[f[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Disk[]]
```

Both give:

> (17 π)/2

---

Visualization:

```
p1 = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}
   , PlotStyle -> None
   , PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}, {0, 10}}
   , ClippingStyle -> None
   , ImageSize -> 400
   ];
p2 = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Disk[]
   , Filling -> Bottom
   , FillingStyle -> Opacity[0.5]
   , PlotRange -> {0, 9}
   ];
Show[p1, p2]
```

[image]

---

**Question**

How can the same problem be set up and solved using polar coordinates? i.e., by manually performing double integration as well as by integrating over a polar region using Mathematica' s `∈` syntax?

---

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
f[x_, y_] := 9 - x^2 - y^2;
Integrate[f[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -Sqrt[1 - x^2], Sqrt[1 - x^2]}]
(* (17 π)/2 *)

IntegrateChangeVariables[
 Inactive[Integrate][f[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -Sqrt[1 - x^2], Sqrt[1 - x^2]}], {r, θ},
 "Cartesian" -> "Polar"]
(* Inactive[Integrate][-r (-9 + r^2), {r, 0, 1}, {θ, -π, π}] *)

Activate[%]
(* (17 π)/2 *)
```

Comment: Thanks. Can `9 - r^2` also be integrated over a polar region? e.g.,  `Integrate[ r ( 9 - r^2), {θ, r} ∈ reg]`? So far I haven't been able to do this.

Answer (score 5):

- Method-1

```
f[x_, y_] := 9 - x^2 - y^2;
reg = ParametricRegion[
  r {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {{t, 0, 2 π}, {r, 0, 1}}]
Integrate[f[x, y], {x, y} ∈ reg]
```

> `(17 π)/2`.

- Mehtod-2

```
Clear[x,y];
f[x_, y_] := 9 - x^2 - y^2;
x[r_, t_] := r*Cos[t];
y[r_, t_] := r*Sin[t];
Integrate[
 f[x[r, t], y[r, t]]*Abs@Det@Grad[{x[r, t], y[r, t]}, {r, t}], {t, 0, 
  2 π}, {r, 0, 1}]
```

> `(17 π)/2`.

- Another example is `ellipsoid`.

```
Clear[f, a, b];
f[x_, y_] := 9 - x^2 - y^2;
{a, b} = {3, 2};
Integrate[f[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Ellipsoid[{0, 0}, {a, b}]]

Clear[x, y];
x[r_, t_] := a*r*Cos[t];
y[r_, t_] := b*r*Sin[t];
Integrate[
 f[x[r, t], y[r, t]]*Abs@Det@Grad[{x[r, t], y[r, t]}, {r, t}], {t, 0, 
  2  π}, {r, 0, 1}]
```

> `(69 π)/2`.

> `(69 π)/2`.

Comment: Thanks. Can `9 - r^2` also be integrated over a polar region? `Integrate[ r ( 9 - r^2), {θ, r} ∈ reg]`? So far I don't know how to do this.

Comment: @Syed Do you mean `Integrate[
 r (9 - r^2), {r, θ} ∈ 
  Rectangle @@ Transpose@{{0, 1}, {0, 2 π}}]` ?

Comment: This is interesting but no. I mean, with the polar region `reg` you have defined above.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the nice answers by @David G. Stork and @cvgmt

Since `IntegrateChangeVariables` is a promising (but a recent) addition, I would like to add this workaround:

```
f[x_, y_] := 9 - x^2 - y^2;
tf = TransformedField[ "Cartesian" -> "Polar", 
   f[x, y], {x, y} -> {r, θ}] // Simplify
```

> 9 - r^2

```
Integrate[ r tf, {r, 0, 1}, {θ, 0, 2 π}]
```

> (17 π)/2

where the calculations for limits of `r` and `θ` are being done manually, something that `IntegrateChangeVariables` provides.

---